# Windows Phone 8 SIM interaction

Tags: windows-phone-8, sim-card

Is it possible to interact with the SIM in windows phone 8 development? I did a bit of research all I could find was that there is no api from Microsoft that allows this, but is there maybe a 3d party app someone knows of?

I am trying to check if a SIM has been changed in a windows phone. So in android terms :

```
    TelephonyManager tm;
    String sim = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
```

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, the Windows Phone SDK does not offer capabilities to interact with the SIM card inserted in the device.