# Monitoring SIM changes in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a windows phone project using C# and Xaml... I will like to get the sim information and also track SIM changes in windows 8.1

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, (assuming a phone restart is needed for a SIM change) if you can get SIM information, can't you track SIM changes by comparing information when you start your application to the information from last time?

Comment: Have not gotten any clue on how to go about it... I can definitely compare information if at all I can get it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the Windows Phone SDK does not allow interaction with the SIM for security reasons. I haven't found a *definitive* source that says so, but the third I would say is a safe bet.

**Sources on StackOverflow**

- ["*Windows Phone 8 SIM interaction*"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17165117/1364007) accepted answer by [Den Delimarsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/303696/den-delimarsky):

  > **No**, the Windows Phone SDK does not offer capabilities to interact with the SIM card inserted in the device.
- ["*How to get sim serial number in Windows programming 8?*"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18980246/1364007) accepted answer by [Matt Lacey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1755/matt-lacey):

  > For security reasons, the SIM number and other personal information are not available in the public SDK for Windows Phone 8.
  >   To uniquely identify a device you can use the [ANID2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.userextendedproperties%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) value.

**Sources on MSDN forums**

- ["*Read Phone number using SDK*"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/af421a11-884e-4e75-b134-904b17796367/read-phone-number-using-sdk?forum=wpdevelop) accepted answer by [RashmiA-MSFT, Microsoft employee](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/rashmia-msft/?type=forum&referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/af421a11-884e-4e75-b134-904b17796367/read-phone-number-using-sdk?forum=wpdevelop):

  > You can use deviceextendedproperties to retrieve device information but it doesn't provide phone number or SIM information. There is no programmatic way to get SIM & phone number information from an app. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties

Comment: No problem. If you feel an answer solved the problem, would you consider marking it as 'accepted'? This way, others will know your question has an answer which has worked for you. Thanks.