# detect SIM card and button pressed event on windows phone 8.1 runtime

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am new in windows phone 8.1 runtime app. I have 2 problems:

1. Can I know SIM card available on phone or not (include invalid SIM)?
2. Can I know when users press start button, volume up/down button and search button? I just find out power, back and camera button because there are API support to do it.

Any help please!
Thank so much!

Comment: Regarding the SIM changes - you might want to look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29572721/1364007) to another question (I think you can't monitor SIM changes).

Comment: Regarding your question as a whole, what have you tried to do to monitor the button presses so far?

Comment: @WaiHaLee: Thank you. I just want to detect SIM card exist on phone or not. And also detect the hardware buttons in use or die. Are there indirect ways to across?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, the phone recognized whether your sim card is valid or invalid.

   > > Go to Settings>> CELLULAR+SIM>> you can see there if your sim read by your phone.

2.There is no start button as like windows PC, all you can see is the main menu on your screen

you can slide to right to show some features installed slide it down to view other settings
and ofcourse its upon to your mobile model :)

Comment: maybe you lost the title. Could you show me how to do in windows phone 8.1 app?